# WPF - custom ToolTip with MultiBinding and different DataContexts

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I want to make a `UserControl` in WPF (C# - MVVM) with a custom two-lines `ToolTip`.

In the View I have a `ListBox` with an `ItemSource` and a custom `ItemTemplate` where to set the previous `ToolTip` that at runtime shows only the first line while the second one is an empty `string`. Indeed the problem is the second line of the `ToolTip` where I use a `MultiBinding` with a converter; converter that fails in `try/catch` returning an empty `string`.

<s>I know that the exception is generated by a value that is `null` while it should be an `int` not nullable, but I don't understand why.</s>
**EDIT:** I was wrong saying `null`; the problem is that the converter strikes a cast exception because of `DependencyProperty UnsetValue`, I don't know why.

Here **Converter** code:

```
public class FromDecimal_MVConverter : Base_MVConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            // Default are 2 decimals
            if (values.Length == 2)
            {
                int decimals;
                switch ((int)values[1])
                {
                    case int dec when dec < 0:
                        decimals = 0;
                        break;
                    case int dec when dec > 99:
                        decimals = 99;
                        break;
                    default:
                        decimals = (int)values[1];
                        break;
                }
                return ((decimal)values[0]).ToString("N" + decimals.ToString());
            }
            else
            {                
                return ((decimal)values[0]).ToString("N2");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public override object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here **XAML** code:

```
...
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{cv_ToString:FromDecimal_MVConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Value"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Decimals" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{cv_ToString:FromDecimal_MVConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Value"/>
                            <Binding Path="Decimals" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
...
```

As you can see `Value` is a property of an object in `ObservableCollection Values`. `Decimals` and `Values` are properties in code behind associated to their dependency properties.

Here `Decimals` definition:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DecimalsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Decimals", typeof(int), typeof(ucMyUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(2) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });

public int Decimals
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(DecimalsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DecimalsProperty, value); }
}
```

I don't understand why for the `TextBlock` outside the `ToolTip` it works and why inside the `ToolTip` not.
How can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How I have solved:**

I have read the comment of @Sinatr about [BindingProxy](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) and finally I have found how to avoid the problem.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="BP_Decimals" Data="{Binding Decimals, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ToolTip>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{cv_ToString:FromDecimal_MVConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Value"/>
                                <Binding Path="Data" Source="{StaticResource BP_Decimals}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid.ToolTip>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
...
```

In this case the `BindingProxy` is binded directly to the `DependencyProperty Decimals`and not to `DataContext`.

Answer (score 1):

The binding fails because the `UserControl` is not a visual ancestor of the `ToolTip`.

You could bind the `Tag` property of the `Grid` to the `Decimals` property and then bind to the `Tag` property using the `PlacementTarget` property of the `ToolTip`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Tag="{Binding Decimals, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <Grid.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{cv_ToString:FromDecimal_MVConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Value"/>
                                <Binding Path="PlacementTarget.Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ToolTip}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Grid.ToolTip>
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work! Can you explain your first line please? If I have more than one property how can I avoid the problem if I can have only one `Tag`?

Comment: @MaxAquila, attached dependency properties may help. Another possibility is to use [BindingProxy](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/), this technique allows you to name and access multiple data contexts.

Comment: @Sinatr, thank you, I have solved the problem with `BindingProxy`.

Comment: @MaxAquila, small but important thing: please post an answer as a separate post. It's [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).